# why in app purchase method run on simulator perfectly but not on real device iOS 6?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, in-app-purchase, xcode4.6, storekit

well this time mi problem is, I did Create an in app purchase method, for buy 2 products,is my first time so, I did learn from the tutorials of raywenderlich [1]:http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial, [2]:http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html and [3]:http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial, the problem is when developing my application, I create the account in the simulator tester and runs perfectly without any error I did test in real device & was run perfectly, but when my application went up to the appstore and approved, I did download the app,I did install it to my iphone and both method not works, not let me buy or restore, not even show me the message dialogs of "use apple id", "create new apple id", "cancel", etc., following the tutorials the code to make it are:

```
     //--- in viewcontroller---//

   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray * productIdentifiers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:INAPP1_ID,INAPP2_ID, nil];

    NSMutableArray * inAppPurchases = [InAppPurchase      initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers delegate:self];

    NSString * msg = nil;

    if (inAppPurchases != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"created %d in-app-purchase objects...", inAppPurchases.count);
        inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO = [inAppPurchases objectAtIndex:0];
        [inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO setVerbose:FALSE];
        inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.progressUploadPurchase = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview: inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.progressUploadPurchase];
        inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.progressUploadPurchase.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
        inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.progressUploadPurchase.labelText = @"Buying...";
        msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product One productId: %@", inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.productId];
        NSLog(@"%@", msg);
        inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO = [inAppPurchases objectAtIndex:1];
        [inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO setVerbose:FALSE];
        inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.progressUploadPurchase = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview: inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.progressUploadPurchase];
        inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.progressUploadPurchase.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
        inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.progressUploadPurchase.labelText = @"Buying...";
        msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product Two productId %@", inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.productId];
        NSLog(@"%@", msg);
    } else {
        msg = @"Error creating in-app purchases objects!";
    }
     NSLog(@"in ViewDidLoad doYouDidBuyPRIMERO %s", doYouDidBuyPRIMERO ? "true" : "false");

     NSLog(@"in ViewDidLoad doYouDidBuySEGUNDO %s", doYouDidBuySEGUNDO ? "true" : "false");

}

-(IBAction)BuyPRIMERO:(id)sender
{
       alreadyPurchased = [inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO alreadyPurchased];
           NSLog(@"%c",alreadyPurchased);
        if (!alreadyPurchased)
        [inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO purchaseProduct];
}

-(IBAction)RestoreBuyPRIMERO:(id)sender
{
     [inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO restorePurchase];
}

-(IBAction)BuySEGUNDO:(id)sender
{
   alreadyPurchased = [inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO alreadyPurchased];
       NSLog(@"%c",alreadyPurchased);
    if (!alreadyPurchased)
        [inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO purchaseProduct];
}

-(IBAction)RestoreBuySEGUNDO:(id)sender
{
    [inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO restorePurchase];
}

- (void)requestedProduct:(InAppPurchase *)iap identifier:(NSString*)productId name:(NSString*)productName price:(NSString*)productPrice description:(NSString*)productDescription {
    NSString * _msg = nil;
    if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO)
    {
        _msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product One is valid %@ price: %@", productName, [iap getValidProductLocalizedPrice]];

        NSLog(@"localized price is %@ (id is %@)", [iap getValidProductLocalizedPrice], [iap getValidProductId]);
        NSString *PRIMERO =[iap getValidProductLocalizedTitle];
        NSLog(@"Title: %@",PRIMERO);
        NSString *pricePRIMERO = [iap getValidProductLocalizedPrice];
        NSString *titlePRIMERO = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Buy %@ %@",PRIMERO,pricePRIMERO];
        PRIMEROFunctionButton.titleLabel.text = titlePRIMERO;
    }  else if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO)
    { 
       _msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product Two is valid %@ price: %@", productName, [iap getValidProductLocalizedPrice]];
         NSLog(@"localized price is %@ (id is %@)", [iap getValidProductLocalizedPrice], [iap getValidProductId]);
        NSString *SEGUNDO =[iap getValidProductLocalizedTitle];
           NSLog(@"Title: %@",SEGUNDO);
        NSString *priceIcons = [iap getValidProductLocalizedPrice];
        NSString *titleIcons = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Buy %@ %@",SEGUNDO,priceSEGUNDO];
        SEGUNDOButton.titleLabel.text = titleSEGUNDO
        ;
    } else {

    }
}

- (void)successfulPurchase:(InAppPurchase*)iap restored:(bool)isRestore identifier:(NSString*)productId receipt:(NSData*)transactionReceipt
{   
    NSString * statusMsg = nil;
    if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO)
    { 
        if (isRestore)
        { 
            statusMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Restored purchase of Product One productId: %@", productId];
            UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Restore Completed" message:statusMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            if ([iap isPurchased])
            {
                doYouDidBuyPRIMERO = YES;
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"DO_YOU_DID_BUY_PRIMERO"];
                NSLog(@"doYouDidBuyPRIMERO %s", doYouDidBuyPRIMERO ? "true" : "false");
                [self HideCancelBuyPRIMERO];
            }

            [inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.progressUploadPurchase hide:YES];

        } else {

            statusMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Purchased Product One productId: %@", productId];
            UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Completed" message:statusMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            if ([iap isPurchased])
            {
                 doYouDidBuyPRIMERO = YES;
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"DO_YOU_DID_BUY_PRIMERO"];
                NSLog(@"doYouDidBuyPRIMERO %s", doYouDidBuyPRIMERO ? "true" : "false");
                [self HideCancelBuyPRIMERO];
            }
            [inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO.progressUploadPurchase hide:YES];
        }

    } else if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO) {

        if (isRestore)
        {
            statusMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Restored purchase of Product Two productId: %@", productId];

            UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Restore Completed" message:statusMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            if ([iap isPurchased])
            {
            doYouDidBuySEGUNDO = YES;

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"DO_YOU_DID_BUY_SEGUNDO"];

            NSLog(@"doYouDidBuySEGUNDO %s", doYouDidBuySEGUNDO ? "true" : "false");
             [self HideCancelBuySEGUNDO];
            }
            [inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.progressUploadPurchase hide:YES];

        } else {

            statusMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Purchased Product Two productId: %@", productId];

            UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Completed" message:statusMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            if ([iap isPurchased])
            {
            doYouDidBuySEGUNDO = YES;

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"DO_YOU_DID_BUY_SEGUNDO"];

            NSLog(@"doYouDidBuySEGUNDO %s", doYouDidBuySEGUNDO ? "true" : "false");
               [self HideCancelBuySEGUNDO];
            }
             [inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO.progressUploadPurchase hide:YES];
        }

    } else {


    }   
}

- (void)failedPurchase:(InAppPurchase*)iap error:(NSInteger)errorCode message:(NSString*)errorMessage {

    NSString * statusMsg = nil;

    if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO)
    {

        statusMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed purchased for Product One!\Error code: %d Error message: %@", errorCode, errorMessage];
        NSLog(@"%@",statusMsg);

    }else if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO) {

        statusMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed purchased for Product Two!\nError code: %d Error message: %@", errorCode, errorMessage];

         NSLog(@"%@",statusMsg);

    }  else {



    }
}

- (void)incompleteRestore:(InAppPurchase*)iap {

    NSString * statusMsg = nil;

    if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO) {

        statusMsg = @"Incomplete restore for Product One!";

         NSLog(@"%@",statusMsg);

    } else if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO) {

        statusMsg = @"Incomplete restore for Product Two!";

         NSLog(@"%@",statusMsg);

    } else {


    }
}

- (void)failedRestore:(InAppPurchase*)iap error:(NSInteger)errorCode message:(NSString*)errorMessage {

    NSString * statusMsg = nil;

    if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductPRIMERO) {

        statusMsg = @"Failed restore for Product One";

         NSLog(@"%@",statusMsg);

    } else if (iap == inAppPurchase_ProductSEGUNDO) {

        statusMsg = @"Failed restored for Product Two!";

         NSLog(@"%@",statusMsg);

    } else {


    }
}

    // AND IN APP PURCHASE HELPER .m

    #import "InAppPurchase.h"

@implementation InAppPurchase

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize validProduct;
@synthesize productId;
@synthesize progressUploadPurchase;

+ (NSMutableArray *)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSArray *)productIdentifiers delegate:(id<InAppPurchaseDelegate>)_delegate {
    NSMutableArray * iapPurchaseArray = nil;

    if (productIdentifiers != nil) {
        InAppPurchase * purchase = nil;
        NSString * productIdentifier = nil;

        iapPurchaseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:productIdentifiers.count];

        for (int i = 0; i < productIdentifiers.count; i++) {
            productIdentifier = [productIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i];
            purchase = [[InAppPurchase alloc] initWithProductId:productIdentifier delegate:_delegate];
            [iapPurchaseArray addObject:purchase];
        }
    }

    return iapPurchaseArray;
}


+ (InAppPurchase *)initWithProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier delegate:(id<InAppPurchaseDelegate>)_delegate {
    InAppPurchase * purchase = nil;

    if (productIdentifier != nil)
        purchase = [[InAppPurchase alloc] initWithProductId:productIdentifier delegate:_delegate];

    return purchase;
}

+ (InAppPopoverView *)showPurchasePopover:(NSArray *)purchases atPoint:(CGPoint)point inView:(UIView *)view withTitle:(NSString *)title includeRestore:(BOOL)includeRestore delegate:(id<InAppPopoverViewDelegate>)delegate {

    InAppPopoverView * inAppPopoverView = nil;

    if (purchases != nil && purchases.count > 0) {
        NSMutableArray * stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        InAppPurchase * inAppPurchase = nil;
        NSString * _productTitle = nil;
        NSString * localizedPrice = nil;
        BOOL wrongClassObject = FALSE;
        BOOL alreadyPurchased = FALSE;

        for (int i = 0; i < purchases.count; i++) {
             inAppPurchase = [purchases objectAtIndex:i];


            if ([inAppPurchase isKindOfClass:InAppPurchase.class])
            {

                if ([inAppPurchase isValidProduct] == FALSE) {
                    NSLog(@"Your purchases NSArray contains some non InAppPurchase that has not been validated!  Please check!");

                    _productTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ not validated yet!", inAppPurchase.productId];
                } else {
                    _productTitle = [inAppPurchase getValidProductLocalizedTitle];
                    alreadyPurchased = [inAppPurchase alreadyPurchased];

                    if (alreadyPurchased) {
                        localizedPrice = [inAppPurchase getValidProductLocalizedPrice];

                        if ([InAppPurchase isRunningIPad])
                            _productTitle = [_productTitle stringByAppendingFormat:@" (already purchased for %@)", localizedPrice];
                        else
                            _productTitle = [_productTitle stringByAppendingFormat:@" (%@)", localizedPrice];
                    } else
                        _productTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Buy %@", [inAppPurchase getValidProductLocalizedTitle]];

                }

                [stringArray addObject:_productTitle];
            } else
                wrongClassObject = TRUE;
        }

        if (wrongClassObject)            
            NSLog(@"Your purchases NSArray contains some non InAppPurchase class objects!  Please check!");
        else {

            if (includeRestore) {
                // last add 'Restore Purchase' which is required by Apple AppStore so good idea to add or have available elsewhere
               [stringArray addObject:@"Restore Purchases"];
            }

           inAppPopoverView = [InAppPopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:view withTitle:title withStringArray:stringArray delegate:delegate];
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"nil InAppPurchases array provided!");
    }

    return inAppPopoverView;
}

+ (BOOL)hasAlreadyPurchased:(NSString *)productId {
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    if (productId != nil)
        result = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productId];

    return result;
}

- (id)initWithProductId:(NSString *)_productId delegate:(id<InAppPurchaseDelegate>)_delegate {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.productId = _productId;
        self.delegate = _delegate;

        purchased = FALSE;
        restored = FALSE;
        verbose = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true" : "false");
        [self requestProduct:self.productId];

        purchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:self.productId];
         NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true" : "false");

        if (purchased)
            NSLog(@"The product %@ is already purchased.", self.productId);

         NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true" : "false");

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setVerbose:(BOOL)_verbose {

    verbose = _verbose;
}

- (BOOL)canMakePayments {

    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

- (BOOL)alreadyPurchased {

    return [self isPurchased];
     NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true alreadyPurchased" : "false alreadyPurchased");
}

- (BOOL)isPurchased
{
    return purchased;
     NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true" : "false");
}

- (BOOL)isRestored {

    return restored;
}

- (BOOL)isValidProduct {
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    if (self.validProduct != nil)
        result = TRUE;

    return result;
}

- (NSString *)getProductId {

    return self.productId;
}

- (SKProduct *)getValidProduct {

    return self.validProduct;
}

- (NSString *)getValidProductId {
    NSString * _id = nil;

    if ([self isValidProduct])
        _id = [self.validProduct productIdentifier];

    return _id;
}

- (NSString *)getValidProductLocalizedDescription {
    NSString * description = nil;

    if ([self isValidProduct])
        description = [self.validProduct localizedDescription];

    return description;
}

- (NSString *)getValidProductLocalizedTitle {
    NSString * title = nil;

    if ([self isValidProduct])
        title = [self.validProduct localizedTitle];

    return title;
}

- (NSString *)getValidProductLocalizedPrice {
    NSString * priceStr = nil;

    if ([self isValidProduct]) {
        NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [numberFormatter setLocale:self.validProduct.priceLocale];

        priceStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:self.validProduct.price];

    }

    return priceStr;
}

- (BOOL)requestProduct:(NSString *)_id {

    if (_id != nil)
    {

        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"InAppPurchase requestProduct: %@", _id);

        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
        {

            SKProductsRequest * prodRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:_id]];
            prodRequest.delegate = self;
            [prodRequest start];
            return YES;

        } else {

            if (verbose)
                NSLog(@"InAppPurchase requestProduct: IAP Disabled");

            return NO;
        }

    } else {

        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"InAppPurchase requestProduct: productId = NIL");

        return NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)purchaseProduct {

    return [self purchaseProduct:self.validProduct];
}

- (BOOL)purchaseProduct:(SKProduct*)requestedProduct
{
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase purchaseProduct: %@", requestedProduct.productIdentifier);
    if (requestedProduct != nil)
    {

        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"InAppPurchase purchaseProduct: %@", requestedProduct.productIdentifier);

        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
        {

            SKPayment *paymentRequest = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:requestedProduct];


            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];


            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:paymentRequest];

            return YES;

        } else {
            if (verbose)
                NSLog(@"InAppPurchase purchaseProduct: IAP Disabled");

            return NO;
        }

    } else {

        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"InAppPurchase purchaseProduct: SKProductis nil");

        return NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)restorePurchase {

    if (verbose)
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase restorePurchase");

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

        return YES;

    } else {


        return NO;
    }
}


- (void)clearUserDefaultsSetting {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:self.productId];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {


    self.validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];

    if (count > 0) {

        self.validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"got valid product %@ for product id %@", self.validProduct, productId);
    }

    if (self.validProduct) {


        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestedProduct:identifier:name:price:description:)])
            [delegate requestedProduct:self identifier:self.validProduct.productIdentifier name:self.validProduct.localizedTitle price:[self.validProduct.price stringValue] description:self.validProduct.localizedDescription];

    } else {

        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestedProduct:identifier:name:price:description:)])
            [delegate requestedProduct:self identifier:nil name:nil price:nil description:nil];
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:


                NSLog(@"1");


                [self.progressUploadPurchase show:YES];


                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:


                purchased = TRUE;
                NSLog(@"2");
                 NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true" : "false");


                purchased product.
                if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulPurchase:restored:identifier:receipt:)])
                    [delegate successfulPurchase:self restored:NO identifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier receipt:transaction.transactionReceipt];


                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:


                purchased = TRUE;
                NSLog(@"3");

                 NSLog(@"purchased %s", purchased? "true" : "false");

                if (!restored && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulPurchase:restored:identifier:receipt:)])
                    [delegate successfulPurchase:self restored:YES identifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier receipt:transaction.transactionReceipt];

                restored = TRUE;

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

                   NSLog(@"4");

                [self.progressUploadPurchase hide:YES];

                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
                {

                    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedPurchase:error:message:)])
                        [delegate failedPurchase:self error:transaction.error.code message:transaction.error.localizedDescription];
                }

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;

        }
    }
}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    if (verbose)
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase removedTransactions");

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    if (verbose)
        NSLog(@"InAppurchase paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished");

    if ([queue.transactions count] == 0) {

        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"InAppPurchase restore queue.transactions count == 0");


        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(incompleteRestore:)])
            [delegate incompleteRestore:self];

    } else {


        if (verbose)
            NSLog(@"InAppPurchase restore queue.transactions available");

        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {

            if (verbose)
                NSLog(@"InAppPurchase restore queue.transactions - transaction data found");

            if (!restored && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulPurchase:restored:identifier:receipt:)])
                [delegate successfulPurchase:self restored:YES identifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier receipt:transaction.transactionReceipt];

            restored = TRUE;
        }
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {


    if (verbose)
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError");

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedRestore:error:message:)])
        [delegate failedRestore:self error:error.code message:error.localizedDescription];
}

#pragma mark - Internal Methods & Events

+ (BOOL)isRunningIPad {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)]) {
        return ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

please, help me guys, if my code is wrong or incomplete, tell me where please!!, i did see another answers from stackoverflow, but, waiting 48 hours, or reset my device, I not find the error, or can not find any explanation to the problem, it seems weird that works the same project before boarding the apsstore and the difference you notice when I download the application if it is the same work project THANKS AGAIN GUYS AND GRETTINGS FROM BOLIVIA ROCK ON!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys.., after waiting two weeks ago I dont Know how but works normally, maybe is like tell us in another questions & just we need wait with more patience, any way, best regards from BOLIVIA!! ROCK ON!!  XD